# I can't use Vue.use to use VueRouter

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, vue-router, vuejs3

I have an issue with vue js , I want to use VueRouter to link 2 vue component, but it seems I have an issue with Vue.use, I have this error : [image]

I don't think the problem is about VueRouter but more about vue import I'm kinda lost at this point

```js
//This is my app.js

import Welcome from "./Jetstream/Welcome";

require('./bootstrap');
window.Vue = require('vue');
console.log(window.vue)

// Import modules...
import { createApp, h } from 'vue';
import Vue from 'vue'
import { App as InertiaApp, plugin as InertiaPlugin } from '@inertiajs/inertia-vue3';
import { InertiaProgress } from '@inertiajs/progress';
import Router from 'vue-router'

Vue.use(Router)

const router = new VueRouter({
    mode: 'history',
    routes:
        {
            path: '/student',
            name: 'student',
            component: Welcome
        },

});

const el = document.getElementById('app');

createApp({
    render: () =>
        h(InertiaApp, {
            initialPage: JSON.parse(el.dataset.page),
            resolveComponent: (name) => require(`./Pages/${name}`).default,
        }),
})
    .mixin({ methods: { route } })
    .use(InertiaPlugin)
    .mount(el);
InertiaProgress.init({ color: '#4B5563' });
```

```html
<template>
<div>Hello</div>
<!-- this is My vue component-->
<!-- i try use a simple method-->
    <a class="btn btn-primary" @click="truc"> Test</a>
<!--And this is what I swa on the documentation-->
    <router-link :to="{name: 'student'}">Student</router-link>

    <div>
        <router-view></router-view>
    </div>

</template>

<script>


export default {
    name: "Session.vue",

    methods:{
        truc(){
            this.$router.push('/student')
        }
    }

}

</script>
```

If you need more content tell me, thanks for your help

```
{
"private": true,
"scripts": {
    "dev": "npm run development",
    "development": "mix",
    "watch": "mix watch",
    "watch-poll": "mix watch -- --watch-options-poll=1000",
    "hot": "mix watch --hot",
    "prod": "npm run production",
    "production": "mix --production"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "@inertiajs/inertia": "^0.9.1",
    "@inertiajs/inertia-vue3": "^0.4.2",
    "@inertiajs/progress": "^0.2.5",
    "@tailwindcss/forms": "^0.2.1",
    "@tailwindcss/typography": "^0.3.0",
    "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.0.5",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "laravel-mix": "^6.0.6",
    "lodash": "^4.17.19",
    "postcss": "^8.1.14",
    "postcss-import": "^12.0.1",
    "tailwindcss": "^2.2.4",
    "vue": "^3.1.5",
    "vue-loader": "^16.1.2"
},
"dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^5.0.2",
    "bootstrap-icons": "^1.5.0",
    "bootstrap-vue": "^2.21.2",
    "vform": "^2.1.0",
    "vue-i18n": "^8.24.5"
}
```

}

this is my package.json

But I have this in my dependencies : [image]

My app.js is now like that :
[image]

[image: [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xEbId.png]

[image]

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dcPUU.png]

Comment: remove the import vue from vue and just leverage the window.Vue.

Comment: @Cameron I already tried that, and same error

Comment: whats your package.json look like?

Comment: Also are you using the .vue() method in your laravel mix? `mix.js('src/app.js', 'dist').vue();`

Comment: yeah you are using vue3,  thats your issue,  see the answer below on migrating from vue2 to vue3 (vuex 2 to 4)  and or downgrade vue in your package json to vue ^2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you use Vue 3, not Vue 2. Because of that you should assign `createApp(...)` to a variable

`let app = createApp(...)`

Also you need to do:

`import {createRouter} from 'vue-router'`

and setup:

`const router = createRouter(...)`

Then you do

`app.use(router)`

See how it looks like in docs:

https://next.router.vuejs.org/guide/#javascript

Comment: Here is a link to breaking changes going form vue2 to vue3,  eg vue-router v2 to v4 https://next.router.vuejs.org/guide/migration/

Comment: I have a "Can't resolve 'vue-router' in my app.js file,  It can't compile @Szymon Pawlus

Comment: But the app.use seems to work, just an issue with vue-router

Comment: It seems like you don't have a vue-router in dependencies in package.json. 
`npm i vue-router`

Comment: @SzymonPawlus He is in my package.json, but the version is underlight in yellow, and when I put my mouse on it I dont have any information, am gonna update my post so you can see it

Comment: I did the npm so now its good but now I have "Uncaught TypeError: (0 , vue_router__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4__.createRouter) is not a function"
And the {createRouter is underlign}

Comment: Just change your version of vue-router to ^4.0.0 or higher (PHPstorm / WebStorm will help you choose highest version)

Comment: @SzymonPawlus Ok so now it's better, but I have now : "Uncaught TypeError: {(intermediate value)} is not a constructor" 
(Thank you for your time really)

Comment: Internet suggest missing semicolon, I see it after your router import, but don't know if it is in your current code

Comment: @SzymonPawlus it seems like my semicolo are ok, I'am gonna edit my post, to show u what its now

Comment: Well, you cannot wrap around createRoute() function with curly braces, they are only for import statements to choose functions and variables to import from file. Then you use them just like a normal function. So you do `const router = createRouter(...)`

Comment: @SzymonPawlus Oh god it never stop, I have now this : "app.js:53258 Uncaught TypeError: routes.forEach is not a function"

Comment: Fortunantely it's easy now. Just wrap you route object in array. Like this:
`const router = createRouter({
mode: "history",
routes: [
{
... // Your route here
},
{
// Another here
}
]
})
`

Comment: @SzymonPawlus Uncaught Error: Provide the "history" option when calling "createRouter()": https://next.router.vuejs.org/api/#history. I did this, but now another error with the history...

Comment: Okay, so after consulting with my friend in Vue3 instead of writing `mode: "history"` you need to write `history: createWebHistory()` but before that you need to also import it from `vue-router` so your import should look like this:
`import { createWebHistory, createRouter } from 'vue-router'` and now i think it shoud be it

Comment: Ok, It's back to App.use is not a function, and when I try to use the VueRouter I have "Cannot read property of "push" of undifined.
You already help me way too much there so I can validate your answer and I will look at by myself from now if you want to stop there

Comment: Well I want to go with it to the end, upload your main.js, and i'll check it

Comment: You mean the main.js with 2461 lines ? that's the only one I have, I think with what I uploaded, you have everything, I'll update the last version of my code but in this laravel +  vue project I dont have a main?js that seems interessting

Comment: Sorry, app.js, sometimes they have different names and i didn't look at the name of yours

Comment: So you have the last version of it in the main post

Comment: Probably `mount(...)` should be separated from 'createApp()' and also should be place after all `app.use(...)` lines so delete `.mount(...)` and write `app.mount(el)`  after `app.use(router)` line